# how to align navigation horizontally and center it?

Tags: css

i need to center the navigation links inside the div, and align it horizontally. I have tried this approach, but did not work.

Fixed the previous error with #centermenu, thanks, but stil does not work.

```
            <nav id="centermenu">
                   <ul>
                         <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Specialities</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul> 
            </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#centermenu {
float: left;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 2px solid #011;
background: #ffe;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#centermenu ul {
float: left;
clear: left;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}


 #centermenu ul li {
display: block;
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 1em;
padding: 1em;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a typing error at the UL-part.

```
Cetermenu ul
```

Instead off

```
Centermenu ul
```

Edit :

The following seems to work for me. Maybe add the other tags one by one to see were it breaks.

```
#centermenu {
float: left;
width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
border-bottom: 2px solid #011;
background: #ffe;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#centermenu ul {
margin: 2 auto;
display: block
}


#centermenu ul li {
display: inline;
text-align: center;
margin: 1em;
padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Fixed the previous error with #centermenu, thanks, but stil does not work. removed the left: 50% declaration as well, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

change your left from 50% to 25%

http://jsfiddle.net/ZW9Qp/

```
    #centermenu {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #011;
    background: #ffe;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    }
    #centermenu ul {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    left: 25%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    }
     #centermenu ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;

}
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not quite in the middel though, need to google a bit more thorough. cheers